# OCaml - Error: Module `Unix' is unavailable

Tags: unix, ocaml

I have been working through Harvard's CS51 class using materials available online. I'm trying to start the final project and downloaded the necessary files, but when I try to compile them I get the following error:

```
Error: Module `Unix' is unavailable (required by `Thread')
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 18 targets (15 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

I have not made any changes to the code I downloaded yet and supposedly I should be able to compile it successfully in its current state. Any ideas why I might be getting this error?

EDIT: Below is the code from the file I downloaded and am trying to compile.

```
module Ev = Evaluation ;;
module MP = Miniml_parse ;;
module ML = Miniml_lex ;;
module Ex = Expr ;;

open Printf ;;

(* str_to_exp str -- Returns the expression specified by `str` using
   the MiniML parser. *)
let str_to_exp (str: string) : Ex.expr =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string str in
  let exp = MP.input ML.token lexbuf in
  exp ;;

(* repl () -- Read-eval-print loop for MiniML, which prompts for and
   evaluates MiniML expressions, printing the resulting value. Exits
   the loop and terminates upon reading an end-of-file
   (control-d). *)
let repl () =
  (* lexical analyzer buffer from stdin *)
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
  (* set up the initial environment *)
  let env = Ev.Env.empty () in

  (* the main LOOP *)
  while true do
    (try
        (* prompt *)
        printf "<== %!";
        
        (* READ and parse an expression from the input *)
        let exp = MP.input ML.token lexbuf in 
        
        (* EVALuate it *)
        let res = Ev.evaluate exp env in
         
        (* PRINT the result; in this initial version, the trivial
           evaluator just returns the expression unchanged as an
           element of the `Env.value` type (found in `expr.ml`), so we
           just extract the expression back out and print it *)
        match res with
        | Val resexp ->
           printf "==> %s\n" (Ex.exp_to_abstract_string resexp)
        | _ -> failwith "not handling other cases yet"
      with
      | MP.Error -> printf "xx> parse error\n"
      | Ev.EvalError msg -> printf "xx> evaluation error: %s\n" msg
      | Ev.EvalException -> printf "xx> evaluation exception\n"
      | End_of_file -> printf "Goodbye.\n"; exit 0
    );
    flush stdout
  done
;;
        
(* Run REPL if called from command line *)

try
  let _ = Str.search_forward (Str.regexp "miniml\\.\\(byte\\|native\\|bc\\|exe\\)")
                             (Sys.argv.(0)) 0 in
  repl ()
with Not_found -> () ;;
```

If I add `open Unix` it does take care of the error above, but I then get a different error:

```
26 |   let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
                                        ^^^^^
Error: This expression has type Unix.file_descr
       but an expression was expected of type in_channel
Command exited with code 2.
```

Comment: Are you using Dune ?

Comment: No I'm not. I'm not really familiar with Dune tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have to explicitly ask to be linked to the `Unix` module.

The following program:

```
$ cat main.ml
Unix.gethostname () |> print_endline
```

would need to be built like this:

```
$ ocamlfind opt -linkpkg -package unix -o main main.ml; echo $?
0
```

whereas the bare minimum would fail with a similar error as yours:

```
$ ocamlopt -o main main.ml; echo $?
File "main.ml", line 1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Unix referenced from main.cmx
2
```

That said, it looks like you're using `Core`, in which case (as well as most
other cases, actually) you're probably better off with [`dune`](https://dune.build/):

```
$ cat dune
(executable
   (name main)
   (libraries unix))

$ dune build main.exe

$ ./_build/default/main.exe
amam-oy
```

However, if you ask Dune to link you to `Core`, `Unix` is already included
automatically, so the following `dune` file would also work for the above
program:

```
$ cat dune
(executable
   (name main)
   (libraries core))
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add

```
open Unix;;
```

at the very start of your .ml file

Comment: Nitpick: In a source file, `;;` should never be needed.

Comment: Also, the question is lacking in details. Without that detail this answer is a bit premature.